# Is there a better method to create such a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want a numpy array like this:

```
b = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
              [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
              [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
              [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
              [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 
              [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
              [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
              [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
              [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```

Is there a faster way to create a NumPy array like this instead of typing them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> np.repeat(np.arange(1, 10).reshape(-1,1), 6, axis=1)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```

Explanation:

- `np.arange(1, 10).reshape(-1,1)` creates an array

```
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

- `np.repeat(_, 6, axis=1)` repeats this 6 times on the first (or second in human words) axis.

Comment: Also maybe this is an XY problem and you need a `np.meshgrid`. Just a wild guess though

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are plenty of methods. This is one:

```
np.repeat(np.arange(1,10),6,axis=0).reshape(9,6)
```

Comment: liked this solution

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use broadcasting:

```
>>> np.arange(1,10)[:,None] * np.ones(6, dtype=int)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.transpose(np.array(([np.arange(1,10)] * 6)))
```

- `np.arange(1,10)` creates an numpy array from 1 to 9.
- `[]` puts the array into a list.
- `*6` augments the array 6 times.
- `np.array()` converts the resulting structure (list of arrays) to a numpy array
- `np.transpose()` rotates the orientation of the numpy array to get vertical one.

Answer (score 0):

For any w*l size, convert a list of lists into an np.array like so:

```
w = 6
l = 9
[np.array([[1+i]*w for i in range(d)])
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])
```